# Component cannot be used a JSX component. > _app.tsx

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-i18next

I'm working with nextjs(TS) and next-i18next but when I install next-i18next my _app.tsx announces the error Component cannot be used a JSX component.
[image]

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).